# Java tcp connection pass value of variable (simple echo server)

Tags: java, php

I have a java code where I am making a tcp connection to a site. Then, after that, I want to pass the value of a variable so that the site will permanently display that value. For example, if I define `int x = 10;` in my java program, I want to pass this value to the site so that it echos that value for ever until a new value is passed. I have no idea how to do this however, is this even possible? Where should I look, in terms of both java and php? Thanks

Comment: You should follow the protocol that site offers you. A connection is merely a tool to be used to pass and receive messages. Which messages you can pass and receive and what the receiver will do in response to those messages is decided by a specific protocol. So what's the protocol of your site?

Comment: I don't know =| As said, I don't know if this is even possible...

Comment: What do you mean by "a site"? It sounds like a running application that writes the transmitted value to it's standard output. Does any of it exist yet? Transporting values from one machine to another requires a protocol, do you have one in mind?

Comment: The short answer is: if you know the protocol and it allows this, then it's possible. If you don't know the protocol, or the protocol doesn't allow this, then it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, when you are creating a tcp-connection, means you are the client and the site you are connected to is the server. I also hope that you are the one in charge of the server here. If that is the case, then what you are looking for is a simple Java server-client system. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) will get you started with that.

If, you are not in charge of the server then you'll just have to create the client part and send data. But that itself probably, won't be sufficient because the server should be able to parse your data. So, you'll have to find out in what format is the server expecting data from the client.